# Subset dataframe using date/time factor variable

Tags: r, datetime, subset

I expect this is a repeat questions, but I have spent many hours now trying to find a solution, and would be very grateful for some help.

I have a the variable `timestamp` in a data frame, currently stored as a factor. `timestamp` is date and time in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ssssss

I would like to be able to subset the dataframe using the timestamp variable taking for instance all the rows between 09/10/2017 00:02:00 and 09/10/2017 00:06:00.

I have tried converting to an ordered factor, and to POSIXlt to help with the subsetting but had no success.

Thank you in advance for any help

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp=c("09/10/2017 00:00:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:01:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:02:00:000000", 
                 "09/10/2017 00:03:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:04:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:05:00:000000",
                 "09/10/2017 00:06:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:07:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:08:00:000000", 
                 "09/10/2017 00:09:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:10:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:00:00:000000", 
                 "09/10/2017 00:01:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:02:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:03:00:000000", 
                 "09/10/2017 00:04:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:05:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:06:00:000000", 
                 "09/10/2017 00:07:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:08:00:000000", "09/10/2017 00:09:00:000000", 
                 "09/10/2017 00:10:00:000000"), b=c (1:22))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the package `lubridate` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select subset by date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244077/select-subset-by-date-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `lubridate`

```
require(lubridate);

# Convert timestamps to POSIXct time&date
df$timestamp <- dmy_hms(gsub(":000000", "", df$timestamp));

# These are your query start/stop dates&times
start <- "09/10/2017 00:02:00";
stop <- "09/10/2017 00:06:00";
interval <- interval(dmy_hms(start), dmy_hms(stop));

# Return entries that fall within query interval
df[df$timestamp %within% interval, ];
#        timestamp  b
#3  2017-10-09 00:02:00  3
#4  2017-10-09 00:03:00  4
#5  2017-10-09 00:04:00  5
#6  2017-10-09 00:05:00  6
#7  2017-10-09 00:06:00  7
#14 2017-10-09 00:02:00 14
#15 2017-10-09 00:03:00 15
#16 2017-10-09 00:04:00 16
#17 2017-10-09 00:05:00 17
#18 2017-10-09 00:06:00 18
```

Or use `subset(df, timestamp %within% interval)` to give the same result. Best to wrap this in a function for more general use.